# Password encryption algorithm

Tags: security, web, passwords

I want to develop a web application where users can login inserting their email and password (chosen when register). I want to know which would be the best password hashing algorithm. I have read that bcrypt is a good option, but what algorithm do sites like facebook use?

Comment: By coding, what have you tried?

Comment: First step, learn the difference between encryption and hashing.  Answer: scrypt or bcrypt.

Comment: It is a JavaEE application. This is a SHA256 algorithm that I am using http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-sha-hashing-example/  , but I want to know the best options

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll want to store a hash and a salt in your database and use those for authentication. This article in particular was very helpful for me when I implemented this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/704865/Salted-Password-Hashing-Doing-it-Right

Answer (score 1):

You should never store a password, even if it is encrypted. Because something that is encrypted can be descrypted, so an attacker could do the same.
Google for "hashing" and "salting", perhaps OWASP has some recommendations how to do this properly. Storing encrypted passwords will be on the list of vulnerabilities to avoid, I think.

Comment: @Adelphia Although I feel a little bit blackmailed, I can answer you this question: you don't store the password in "clear text", you simply store its hash which is calculated through a clever algorithm which is not reverseable. In short: if you save a password in a file, an attacker can grab this file and then he knows your password. If you store a hash (which is just a number of hex values like '2a73f5b8b625a600c180ea44fe04e8c2dec52311' he did not gain much. When a user enters a password in your application you simply calculate the hash and compare it to the stored value.

Comment: @Adelphia I'm still waiting ;-)

Answer (score -2):

I have written an 2 functions for handling passwords.  The first one accepts a string (i.e. your password) and returns a seeded hash.  It takes an MD5 hash of the time and prepends it to the string.  It then takes a SHA256 hash of that string.  It then prepends the original MD5 hash to the SHA256 hash.  The function returns this 96-character string.  The second function takes 2 strings as this arguments (the password being tested and the password hash you are tested it against) and returns a Boolean value.  This is PHP, but the logic is of course transferable.

```
function hash_password( $password ){
    $md5 = strtoupper( hash( 'md5', time() ) );
    $hash = $md5 . strtoupper( hash( 'sha256', $md5 . $password ) );
    return $hash;
    }

function test_password( $password, $hash ){
    $md5 = substr( $hash, 0, 32 );
    $sha256 = substr( $hash, 32 );

    if( $sha256 == strtoupper( hash( 'sha256', $md5 . $password ) ) )
        return true;
    else
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: This is a solved problem. You should not write your own!

Comment: PHP has builtin functionality: [password_hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php).

Comment: SHA-* is **not** appropriate to hash passwords, because it is way too fast and therefore can be brute-forced too easily. Instead us a slow hash function with a cost factor, like BCrypt or PBKDF2. The password_hash() was written exactly to avoid such code with MD5 and SHA-*.